# Auto fill for 2nd date field not working properly - jQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, autocomplete, datepicker

I am trying to auto populate the "end_date" field based on the number of days the user enters in the "days" field. For example, user enters 2 in days field. User then proceeds to select a start date of 04/27/2016. The end date should be filled with 04/29/2016. I am not very familiar with javascript and I have spent hours searching but no answer so far. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
</html>

<input id='days' class='days' type='text'/>
<input id='start_date' class='start_date' type='text'/>
<input id='end_date' class='end_date' type='text'/>


<script>
$(function() {
$(".days").val();
$(".end_date").datepicker();
$(".start_date").datepicker({
onSelect:function(){
var x = $(".days").val();
var toDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
toDate.setDate(toDate.getDate() + x)
$(".end_date").datepicker("setDate", toDate);
}
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Use this code instead of your code :

var x = $("#days").val();

Comment: Check it and let me know

Comment: @Dilip I just tried it and still no luck. It shows the wrong date. If I enter 1 day and 4/01/2016 for start, end date shows 4/11/2016. Maybe some kind of formatting issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept trying a few things and was able to figure out a way to make this code work. This might not be the best way to do this but it works for what I am trying to do. I changed this line of code from     toDate.setDate(toDate.getDate() + x) to     toDate.setDate(toDate.getDate() + (x / 1)).

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
</html>

<input id='days' class='days' type='text'/>
<input id='start_date' class='start_date' type='text'/>
<input id='end_date' class='end_date' type='text'/>


<script>
$(function() {
$(".on_site_days").val();
$(".audit_end_date").datepicker();
$(".audit_start_date").datepicker({
onSelect:function(){

dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy'

var x = $(".on_site_days").val();
var toDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
toDate.setDate(toDate.getDate() + (x / 1))
$(".audit_end_date").datepicker("setDate", toDate);
}
});
});
</script>
```